# Is the Windows 7 default graphic driver faster than the newest NVIDIA Forceware?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

Here is my Windows 7 Experience Index using the stock graphics driver:

[image: Stock driver]

And after installing the newest driver Forceware 197.45, it becomes:

[image: Forceware 197.45]

The only change is that **the "Gaming graphics" subscore drops from 6.4 to 5.2.**

Is the stock graphic driver more optimized for Windows 7? Or is Forceware 197.45 buggy? **Should I revert back to the stock driver?**

My configuration:

- Athlon 64 X2 5000+
- Asus M2A-VM (AMD 690G, SB600)
- 6 GB DDR2-800 RAM (only 3.25 GB usable under Windows)
- GeForce 8600 GT (256 MB)
- Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't trust Windows Experience Index "rater" to be *any* sort of benchmarking tool. Get your hands on [3D Mark '06](http://www.futuremark.com/benchmarks/3dmark06/download/) / [3D Mark Vantage](http://www.futuremark.com/benchmarks/3dmarkvantage/download/), run the benchmarks for couple of times and compare the scores to see which one is better.

For the record, based on my previous experiences, Nvidia's latest Forceware drivers are *always* better than Windows' stock drivers.

(PS: Not sure why you're using 32-bit edition of Windows, with as much as 6GB of RAM. You **should** move on to 64-bit edition to make use of all available RAM).

Comment: use the 64 bit version of windows!

Comment: The Index is never an accurate measure of performance, but a drop from 6.4 to 5.2 most probably means something is wrong, be it the driver or the Index itself. 3D Mark is definitely a better tool; if I have time I'll see what it tells me. BTW, I do make use of the unaddressable RAM with a 2.75GB ramdrive (check out superspeed.com if you don't think it can be done:)

Comment: @netvope - Nice use of RAMdisks.